# How to check if two sets are disjoint?

Tags: c++, c++11

The objective is to check if two set's are disjoint or not, and here's the code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

bool isDisjoint(int set1[], int len1, int set2[], int len2); 
int main()
{
    int set1[] = {10, 5, 3, 4, 6};
    int set2[] = {8, 7, 9, 3};
    if (isDisjoint(set1,sizeof(set1),set2,sizeof(set2)))
        cout<<"DISJOINT";
    else
        cout<<"NOT DISJOINT";

    return 0;
}

bool isDisjoint(int set1[], int len1, int set2[], int len2)
{
    unordered_set<int> set;


    for(int i=0;i<len1;i++)
        set.insert(set1[i]);

    for(int j=0;j<len2;j++)
    {
        if(set2[j]==set.find(set2[j]))
    //-----------^^^^-----------------
            return false;

    }

    return true;
}
```

However, as shown in comment, I get an issue when I try to check whether the element exist in unordered set :

> invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and
>         'iterator' (aka '__hash_const_iterator
>         *>'))

I tried referring the docs [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) and [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) , however it did not help to fix the issue but left me more perplexed since I am from a Java background. Any help to solve this issue will be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Check out [std::set_difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- `std::set_difference` requires **sorted** input sequences; it won't work with unsorted sets, despite its name.

Comment: If you want to use that O(n^2) algorithm, you don't need to copy the data into those intermediate `std::unordered_set`s; just do the searches and comparisons on the arrays. For larger data sets, either sort your arrays or copy the data into two `std::set` objects and then use `std::set_difference`.

Comment: @PeteBecker How come it comes to `O(n^2)` , searching in hashtable takes close to `O(1)` . So it won't go beyond `O(n)` . Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: @OBX - whoops, sorry. You're right: absent perverse conditions, it's O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check should be against `set.end()`, not against `set2[j]`:

```
if (set.find(set2[j]) != set.end()) {
    ...
}
```

Note that you call `isDisjoint` passing `sizeof(set1)` and `sizeof(set2)`, which is incorrect: you should be passing `sizeof(set1)/sizeof(set1[0])` or [`std::size(set1)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) in C++17.

Comment: that's interesting, I ran the program, and it successfully run, why is it incorrect to use sizeof(set1) ? :/

Comment: @OBX Because `sizeof` returns size in bytes. On 32-bit platform `sizeof(set1)` in your program is 20. `isDisjoint` will use five items from the array, followed by 15 more items of "garbage" after them. This behavior is undefined: you may get a wrong answer or a crash.

Answer (score 1):

`find` returns an `iterator`, see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/find/).

Just replace

```
if(set2[j]==set.find(set2[j]))
```

with

```
if(set.find(set2[j]) != set.end())
```

Furthermore, `sizeof(set1)` returns the size in bytes of the set. In order to get the real number the number of the elements you have to divide by `sizeof(int)`, hence:

```
sizeof(set1)/sizeof(int)
```

This will turn this line of code:

```
if (isDisjoint(set1,sizeof(set1),set2,sizeof(set2)))
```

into this:

```
int set1_size = sizeof(set1)/sizeof(int);
int set2_size = sizeof(set2)/sizeof(int);

if (isDisjoint(set1,set1_size,set2,set2_size)
    //blah blah the rest
```